# ReactJS: Contents of a component not updating when a function inside render() is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I am trying to achieve something but I am not sure this is the best way to do it:

I have an array of products (productArray) that is displayed inside `<ProductDisplay />` component. I also have a `<FilterPanel />` that allows me to sort the elements inside productArray. Both `<ProductDisplay />` and `<FilterPanel />` are wrapped within a hoc called `<MainContainer />`, in the following style:

```
<MainContainer>
    <FilterPanel />
    <ProductDisplay />
</MainContainer>
```

`<MainContainer />` has a sorting function within its render() method. The sorting function is passed to `<FilterPanel />`, and when called, it sorts the productArray. The sorted productArray is passed from `<MainContainer />` to `<ProductDisplay />`

Here is a simplified code of `<MainContainer />`:

```
//import sorting functions: categorySort, timeSort, and ratingSort

class MainContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      sort: ""
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { productArray } = this.props; //getting an array of products from props

    let sortResult = productArray; //if no sorting selected, sortResult will be the default order
  
    const performSort = (sortType) => {
      this.setState({sort: `${sortType}`}); //not really important

      switch(sortType) {
        case 'time':
          sortResult = timeSort(productArray); //gets sorted when called
          break;
        case 'category':
          sortResult = categorySort(productArray); //gets sorted when called
          break;
        case 'rating':
          sortResult = ratingSort(productArray); //gets sorted when called
        break;
        default:
          console.log('default case')
      }
    }

    console.log( `sortResult final`);
    console.log(sortResult);        //does not reflect sorting done above; still in initial state

    return (
      <div>
          <FilterPanel performSort={performSort}/>
          <ProductDisplay sortResult = {sortResult} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When the sorting function 'performSort' is called from `<FilterPanel />` it successfully produces a sorted 'sortResult' array within the switch statement, however, the 'sortResult' outside (after) the switch statement is not changing (and is being passed down to `<ProductDisplay />` unchanged). Which is weird because 'sortResult' is supposed to be within the scope of the switch statement.

Any help in figuring this out is hugely appreciated (also, any suggestions on how this could be done better. Note that I haven't learned hooks yet, so I prefer a solution without hooks).

Comment: I believe in order for the data to re-render, you would need to `setState`. Why not add `sortResult` to your `state` object, and after the `switch`, `setState({sortResult})`? Also, how come you have so much logic in your `render` method as opposed to it's own outside of `render()`?

Comment: I actually put it inside render so that it could modify 'sortResult' that was initially initialized there. I think I get it now that it won't modify it unless I put 'sortResult' in the state, so I will be moving the function outside of render()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React components only re-render when their passed-in props change, or their state changes, or a context they use changes. (Or, in React Router, when the URL changes.)  This basic fact is a key part of understanding React.

In this case, you *are* changing a Javascript variable ... but not one of the three (four) things I mentioned.

To solve this you can make `sortResult` a part of your state (ie. `this.state.sortResult`), then `setState` it after you finish sorting.  Because that *will* change state, it will cause your component to re-render, and generate fresh DOM from your returned JSX.

Comment: Thank you! I thought earlier that the issue could be with re-rendering, but then thought that either way, sortResult would still need to be modified outside the switch (and that this is a separate problem). I realize now that only what lies within performSort function woould be altered, but the component wouldn't notice that anything was altered because it didn't rerender - hence the sortResult array that lies outside performSort function would stay the same. I guess I am talking to myself here - thank you for the explanation!